# jQuery refresh data received from json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get data from another server and display it on my web site. The remote server uses jsonp so I am using jQuery. My code looks something like this:

```
$.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push("<li id=" + key + ">" + val + "</li>");
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join("")
  }).appendTo("#my-id");
});
```

I want to make another request after one minute to check if there are new data so I might use `setInterval(main, 60000)` or something like this.

But the problem is that when I get the new data, the old one isn't cleared. So I will have `li` element with the old and new value.

How should I change my code so that it would clear the old data?

Comment: Please show how you are using `setInterval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$("#my-id").html($( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join("")
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear your `<ul>` with `.empty()` method before appending the new items like this:

```
$.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push("<li id=" + key + ">" + val + "</li>");
  });

  $("#my-id").empty();

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join("")
  }).appendTo("#my-id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
$("#my-id").empty();
```

at the beginning of the callback function. `.appendTo` does what its name implies, it appends to the element instead of replacing the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `appendTo` thus old data is not cleared.

Use

```
 $("#my-id").html($( "<ul/>", {
  "class": "my-new-list",
  html: items.join("")
 }));
```

or clear using

```
$("#my-id").html('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery remove

```
$("#my-id").remove();
```

You can remove data contain elements and add it again

Answer (score 0):

Just clear `ul` before appending `li` items. You can use `$('ul-id').empty()` or `$('ul-id li').detach()`.